# Retrieving Auth user data from Database (Laravel)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I seek to learn more about Retrieving user information from Database.

I have a website where you can send a message **from_id, to_id.**

When people register, there data get inserted in a **table users**.

**Users table contains:
uid(from_id), email, tokenn**

**Posts table contains:
message, from_id, to_id**

I created an php file that will push notification for a user tokenn and added this code to:
\sup\app\Http\Controllers
**postsController.php**

Here's my post function that posts a message from user to another with push notification function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\post;
use Auth;
use Lang;

class postsController extends Controller
{
    public function send_feedback(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'feedback_image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:3072',
            'feedback_content' => 'required|max:500'
        ]);
        $pid = rand(9,999999999)+time();
        if (Auth::user()) {
            $from_id = Auth::user()->uid;
        }elseif (Auth::guest()) {
            $from_id = 0;
        }
        $to_id = $request['hidden2'];
        $feedback = $request['feedback_content'];
        $image = $request->file('feedback_image');
        $time = $request['hidden'];
        if ($request->hasFile('feedback_image')) {
            $img_ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $img_name = rand(9,9999999)+time()+rand(0,55555).".".$img_ext;
            $img_new = $image->storeAs("fbImgs",$img_name);
        }else{
            $img_name = "";
        }
        $post = new post();
        $post->pid = $pid;
        $post->from_id = $from_id;
        $post->to_id = $to_id;
        $post->feedback = $feedback;
        $post->image = $img_name;
        $post->time = $time;
        $post->save();


//

**define('xxxxx');
 $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 $token='{{ Auth::user()->tokenn }}';
    $notification = [
            'title' =>'XXX',
            'body' => 'XXXX',
            'icon' =>'myIcon', 
            'sound' => 'mySound'
        ];
        $extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification,"moredata" =>'dd'];
        $fcmNotification = [
            //'registration_ids' => $tokenList, //multple token array
            'to'        => $token, //single token
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];
        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;**
        

//
        return redirect()->back()->with('feedback_sent',Lang::get('trans.fb_sent'));
    }
    public function postPrivacy(Request $request){
        $pid_var = $request['pid'];
        $pid_ex = explode("_", $pid_var);
        $pid = @$pid_ex[1];
        if ($request['status'] == "true") {
            $updatePrivacy = post::where('pid',$pid)->update(['privacy' => 1]);
        }else{
            $updatePrivacy = post::where('pid',$pid)->update(['privacy' => 0]);
        }
        return $pid;
    }
    public function deletePost(Request $request){
        $checkID = post::where('pid',$request['pid'])->get()->count();
        if ($checkID > 0) {
            $allowed = post::where('pid',$request['pid'])->get();
            foreach ($allowed as $getAllowed) {
                $to_id = $getAllowed->to_id;
                $from_id = $getAllowed->from_id;
            }
            if ($to_id == Auth::user()->uid || $from_id == Auth::user()->uid) {
                $deleteFB = post::where('pid',$request['pid'])->delete();
                return "done";
            }else{
                return Lang::get('trans.delPost_notAllowed');
            }
        }else{
            return Lang::get('trans.err_somethingWrong');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

As you can see,  **$token='{{ Auth::user()->tokenn }}';**, Token should get current user's tokenn, the recipient token from users table but I don't know how?
I tried to declare new variable as follows: $tokenn = Auth::user()->tokenn but it is not working. I'm messing something. I searched whole project where to declare and retrieve column name of token but I don't know where.

**Edit:**

changed $token='{{ Auth::user()->tokenn }}'; to $token=Auth::user()->tokenn; as I have been informed.

It is working but in this case $token is recieving logged in user token and sends the sender a notification. I want to push notification for the recipient of the message something like $token=Auth::user()->to_id->tokenn;

Comment: change `$token='{{ Auth::user()->tokenn }}';` to `$token=Auth::user()->tokenn;` also make sure the user is logged in and the token stored in database is valid.

Comment: Is the user actually authenticated?

Comment: @MohsenNazari it is not working.

Comment: @MuaRachmann, Yes, I'm sure, but what is the best way to check authentication ?

Comment: @MohsenNazari, Edit. It is working but in this case $token is recieving logged in user token and sends the sender a notification.
I want to push notification for the recipient of the message something like $token=Auth::user()->to_id->tokenn;

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to get the other user's **tokenn** (to_id user), try this code:

```php
$token = User::find($to_id)->tokenn;
```

in case if `to_id` is the column `uid` inside your table, then you should use this:

```php
$token = User::where('uid', $to_id)->first()->tokenn;
```

also you need to make sure that the other user exists, from request validation or using `findOrFail` instead of `find` or `firstOrFail` instead of `first`.

**Update:**

Instead of curl, you can use Laravel native `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http` wrapper which makes debugging easier. I translated  your code:

```php
<?php

class postsController extends Controller
{
    public function send_feedback(Request $request)
    {
        // codes before ....

        $apiAccessKey = "some key";
        $token = "something";
        $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        $notification = [
            'title' => 'XXX',
            'body' => 'XXXX',
            'icon' => 'myIcon',
            'sound' => 'mySound'
        ];
        $extraNotificationData = [
            "message" => $notification,
            "moredata" => 'dd'
        ];
        $fcmNotification = [
            'to' => $token,
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];

        $response = Http::acceptJson()
            ->withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'key=' . $apiAccessKey
            ])->post(
                $url,
                $fcmNotification
            );

        dd($response->json());
    }
}
```

Comment: None worked, I guess I'm one step from getting it working. I edited my tables. Please check it.  any soultion ?

Comment: use `dd(User::where('uid', $to_id)->first())` and see if the target user is found. If it is found and the token is correct, then there might be some issues with the way you call the API. To make sure the curl call is working correctly, choose one of your users and hard-code it inside your token and test it.

Comment: if i choose any user token directly it works fine. the problem is that a guest can send a message to registered user too. I want to target the recipients token. Let me test somethings and I will tell you what happened!